# When hovering on one link - change the style of all the other links

Tags: css, hover

I have a list of links. When I hover/focus on one of them. I would like to change the style of the links that aren't hovered on.

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li {
list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 15px;
opacity: 1;
}

a:hover {
color: black;
}

a:hover li a {
opacity: 0.5
}
```

This would usually work changing the style of a different element but this logic doesn't seem to work on the links.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `<li>` elements should be wrapped in a `<ul>` parent.  Otherwise, this is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the effect to all links using `nav:hover a`.

Add the effect to a single link using `nav li a:hover`

As noted in comments, your HTML is invalid. `<li>` must be child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav:hover a {
  opacity: .5;
}

nav li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```